# CSS - Style the first 3 lines of a paragraph?

Tags: css

I am trying to determine if it's possible via CSS to always style the first 3 lines of a paragraph.  This would need to take into account a responsive layout, so the first 3 lines will change depending on the width of the browser.

I know there is ::first-line, but can it be manipulated at all to handle the first 3 lines?

```
::first-line
```

Comment: No, I don't believe with CSS alone that this is possible.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? color? font-size ? ...

Comment: I don't think there is a current CSS implementation for this, however, there is an interesting javascript solution by James Nowland - http://codepen.io/jnowland/pen/AifjK/

Comment: I am trying to keep the first 3 lines bold and a different colour.

Comment: you can play with mix-blend-mode eventually http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qboMxg

Answer (score 0):

just for the fun, check caniuse.com before spending sometimes in it:

```css
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  color:black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.9em;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);/* rgba() as for a fallback */
  pointer-events:none;/* cause maybe text, forms and links deserve to be reached via the mouse ;) */
}
```

```html
<p>Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `<span>` around the first three lines, which will not change the display type of the lines because spans are inline elements. Then give that span a class or id and have that class or id kick in using media queries.

For example, on smaller screen sizes you could do:

```
.intro-lines {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

And then on larger screen sizes, you can reset the CSS properties to their defaults:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {

    .intro-lines {
        font-size: normal;
    }

}
```